# Can FoneMonkey be used for testing preinstalled apps or apps for which we dont have source code?

Tags: iphone, ios-ui-automation

Can we use fonemonkey to test preinstalled apps in iphone.
if so, can you guide me.

or

If it is possible to test an app for which i dont have sourcecode, pls guide me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, FoneMonkey needs to be compiled with the app, so you need to have the souces